# : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in laravel migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

In my migration file , I am adding organization id to the user's table , i tried all of the code below but not solved yet

```
class AddOrganizationIdToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->foreignId('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('organization_id')->constrained('organizations')->cascadeOnDelete();
//            $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you edit your post to include your migration files ?

Comment: It should be  `$table->foreignId('organization_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: your organization table would need to be added in migrations prior to this migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have data on my user's table so it is giving errors while migrating, to solve it I add the field as nullable

```
$table->foreignId('organization_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you write with `foreignId` need:

```
$table->foreignId('organization_id')->constrained('organizations')->cascadeOnDelete();
```

or just `foreign`

```
$table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Do you have `organizations` table? need migrate that table first

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'organization_id' doesn't exist in table

Comment: i am migration both migration at the same time organization first then add organization id to users

Comment: need more info. Add to question all implicated migrations

Comment: I have updated mu code to new, please have a look at it

Comment: try create `organization_id` before foreign. And look that type with organizations.id will be same. In my case its bigInteger unsigned...

Comment: I am use Laravel 7 and in my working migrations i have:
`$table->foreignId('phone_id')->constrained('phones')->nullOnDelete();` without any prepared fields. just on create table (or on update like Schema::table(''))

Answer (score 0):

What could be the issue is that this migration is running before the **organizations** table migration, and when it tries to find it to create the constraint it fails.

What I would suggest is on the AddOrganizationIdToUsersTable :

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('organization_id');
        });
```

And on the Organization creation migration:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations');
        });
```

#2 solution:
Move the migration of Organization table to run before your AddOrganizationIdToUsersTable by changing the timestamp on the name of the file